# How do you connect to FTP server via a shell-script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am writing my first shell-script ever and I am trying to connect to an FTP server. However, I am utterly at a loss for how to do this. I tried a google search, but I am still stumped.

I am trying to connect with a username and password (not a ssh id).

Thanks for your help. Again this is my first shell-script ever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `man ftp` should give you the necessary pointers.
This being said, [this page](http://www.mysysad.com/2008/01/ftp-using-shell-script.html) might help you build a complete shell script

Answer (score 7):

Here how you connect to FTP server via a shell-script :

```
nano MyConnectFTPScript.sh

#!/bin/sh
$HOST='hostAdresss'
$USER='NameOfUser'
$PASSWD='YourPass'
$FILEtoPut='myFile1'
$FILEtoGet='myFile2'
$FILEtoDelete='myFile3'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD

put $FILEtoPut
get $FILEtoGet
delete $FILEtoDelete

quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0

chmod +x MyConnectFTPScript.sh
```

and execute :
    ./MyConnectFTPScript.sh

I hope these will be helpful.
Samir